# The description for Meta Gaming is wrong

Tags: bug, status-completed, site-attributes

As seen [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114673/can-i-see-things-that-ive-said-in-chat-that-have-been-starred): (emphasis mine)

> migrated from [meta.gaming.stackexchange.com](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3356/can-i-see-things-that-ive-said-in-chat-that-have-been-starred?noredirect=1) just now
>
> This question came from **our site for passionate videogamers on all platforms.**

Comment: How is this wrong exactly? It came from Gaming, did it not?

Comment: @ArdaXi Obviously badp thinks our site is about bird watching.

Comment: @ArdaXi __meta.gaming__, not gaming.

Comment: Meta.gaming is the meta discussion section of our site for gamers. I fail to see the problem.

Comment: @badp You'd prefer it to be "discussion, support, and feature requests for this site"? This is fine. It came from meta.gaming to meta.SO, the 'meta' is implied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been addressed. I'll just copy [Geoff Dalgas's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116970/wrong-migration-text-for-questions-from-meta-tex-sx/117250#117250) from MSO:

> When questions are migrated from a meta site the migration text will now read:
>
> > This question came from our discussion, support, and feature requests
> >     site for *audience*.
>
> This will be in after the next deploy.

Answer (score 3):

This is actually a long-standing bug that has been reported - because you'll also get this error if you, say, [migrate from a meta site to its own main site](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30326/is-tex-as-word-and-logo-a-trade-mark), which has a slight weirdness to it (since main -> meta migrations *don't* sport that weirdness).

This is currently low-ish priority.

Comment: Yeah, actually that bug report is why I made on Gaming too. I thought it was just something that only affected a few meta's.